# How to take the closest/nearest element of a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the closest/nearest class of a specific element.

How can I make it work? I am currently trying to use .closest.

HTML

```
<div class="test">.test</div>    <!-- Not this -->
<div>
   <div class="test">.test</div> <!-- That's the one I need to grab -->
</div>
<div id="test"></div>            <!-- This is the reference element -->
<div class="another"></div>
<div class="another"></div>
<div class="test">.test</div>
```

JS

```
var test = $('#test2').closest('.test');
console.log(test);
```

If closest isn't the right method, how can I actually grab the closest 'test' class?

I tried parentsUntil() as well.

Actually if that can help, in my use case I will ALWAYS need the nearest PARENT element of a specific class, whether that parent element is within another element or not, like in this HTML example.

Comment: Which element do you want, the .test before it or after it? BTW, .closest traverses up the DOM. Oh, and divs don't have value attributes; inputs do.

Comment: I want the closest test above it.

Comment: In my use case, it would literally be the "closest" regardless of up or down.

Comment: So you mean the nearest one instead???  If you check closest() doc, you'll see why your question doesn't make much sense

Comment: Yeah nearest is a good synonym

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Still, not sure which one is the nearest one. That's why btw there isn't any method call nearest() on jQuery, because it will be quite ambiguous method

Comment: Look at my revised question I put a comment in the HTML. It is the nearest one from id "test2" and I need to grab it.

Comment: In your particular case I would think that you have to walk both ways, one going up the DOM and another going down, searching on every node for a matching test element or descendant.

Comment: I tried parentsUntil but that didn't work either

Comment: Why upper one is 'nearest'? http://jsfiddle.net/kuga74c4/11/ But, since HTML code will be changed, this will not work in some other case... quite ambiguous, and... not sure that universal solution is possible at all...

Comment: Basically I need the first parent element of specific class. Whether that parent element is within another element or not...

Comment: edited my answer. It's working if you use prevAll() in combination with :first

Comment: Do you need to search upwards, too?

Comment: The search should stop when matching the first parent element of class "test" in this case which is within divs

Comment: @robertparé see if my answer helps. Does not search upwards (can edit if you post an example).

Comment: Please view the updated code, Its the plugin designed to find the nearest element which matches the selector `.test` in this case.

Comment: Look at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp :

>The closest() method returns the first ancestor of the selected element.
An ancestor is a parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly then you are looking for the nearest element that appears before a specific element in HTML source order (and you do not know/cannot change the HTML structure). The simplest solution is this:

[`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) collections are sorted in the order in which the elements appear in DOM (unless the documentation states otherwise). So we have:

```
$("#test, .test")
// [div.test, div.test, div#test, div.test]
//            ^         ^
//            |         +---- reference element
//            +-------------- nearest element before it
//
// notice that the elements are sorted in the order they appear in HTML
```

Just combine this with [`jQuery.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```js
$(function() {
  var $ref = $("#test");
  var $col = $(".test").add($ref);
  var index = $col.index($ref);
  $col.eq(index - 1).css("background-color", "orange");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">.test</div>   <!-- Not this -->
<div>
  <div class="test">.test</div> <!-- That's the one I need to grab -->
</div>
<div id="test"></div>           <!-- This is the reference element -->
<div class="another"></div>
<div class="another"></div>
<div class="test">.test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why your HTML is structured like that, but this should select your required div:

```
$('.test',$('#test2').prev('div')).text() // find a div with class test, contained within div that lies previous to #test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest searches for parent elements in DOM tree. For siblings you cannot easily get the nearest as such, but if you know direction up/down you can select from .nextAll('.test:first') and prevAll('.test:first').